# Order columns containing a string first in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame containing multiple rows with different phrases separated with commas like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'phrase':['dog, cat, cow','bird, cat','cow, bird','dog, cow','bird'],
})
>>> df
          phrase
0  dog, cat, cow
1      bird, cat
2      cow, bird
3       dog, cow
4           bird
```

I want to order so that rows that have 'bird' in the column `phrase` are on the first rows like this:

```
          phrase
0      bird, cat
1      cow, bird
2           bird
3  dog, cat, cow
4       dog, cow
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for boolean mask, invert condition and call [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) for positions, last change ordering by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.iloc[(~df['phrase'].str.contains('bird')).argsort()]
print (df)
          phrase
1      bird, cat
2      cow, bird
4           bird
0  dog, cat, cow
3       dog, cow
```

**Detail**:

```
a = df['phrase'].str.contains('bird')
b = (~df['phrase'].str.contains('bird'))
c = (~df['phrase'].str.contains('bird')).argsort()
print (df.assign(contains=a, invert=b, argsort=c))
          phrase  contains  invert  argsort
0  dog, cat, cow     False    True        1
1      bird, cat      True   False        2
2      cow, bird      True   False        4
3       dog, cow     False    True        0
4           bird      True   False        3
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sorted` with a custom `key`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'phrase':['dog, cat, cow','bird, cat','cow, bird','dog, cow','bird']})
df["New"] = pd.Series(sorted(df["phrase"].tolist(), key=lambda x: 0 if "bird" in x else 1))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
          phrase            New
0  dog, cat, cow      bird, cat
1      bird, cat      cow, bird
2      cow, bird           bird
3       dog, cow  dog, cat, cow
4           bird       dog, cow
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some "has bird" column, sort by it, and drop it if needed.

```
(df.assign(has_bird=df.phrase.apply(lambda l: 'bird' in l))
    .sort_values(by='has_bird', ascending=False)
    .drop('has_bird', axis=1))
    phrase
1   bird, cat
2   cow, bird
4   bird
0   dog, cat, cow
3   dog, cow
```

You can use [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), `sort_values`, and `drop` to chain.

In case you have an old version of pandas, use

```
df['has_bird'] = df.phrase.apply(lambda l: 'bird' in l))
df.sort_values(by='has_bird', ascending=False).drop('has_bird', axis=1)
```

Comment: @SabiriS Yes I have. Your pandas version must be very old (before 16). I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an additional column with boolean based on the condition and then sort by that column. Below code should work.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'phrase':['dog, cat, cow','bird, cat','cow, bird','dog, cow','bird']})
df['bird_exists'] = df['phrase'].apply(lambda x : 'bird' in x.lower())

df = df.sort_values('bird_exists', ascending=False)

print(df.head())
```